# Buffered zipped stream C++

Tags: c++, stream, zip, client-server, buffer

Server needs to send very large zip file to client. The zipped file cannot be kept in its entirety in memory (too large) or written to disk (several files being sent concurrently may be too big for the hard disk) - it must be streamed directly to client.

Any simple approahces to this? From what I gather the zip format has a CRC in its header so you can't actually stream the zip without creating it in its entirety... 
If it cannot be done with zip files please suggest an alternative format. Thanks.

Comment: I imagine the title of this question submitted to Google would be fairly informative.

Comment: I could not find a straightforward answer to this question in my 20minute searches. There are many solutions not suitable to my case because they either keep the zipped file in memory or create a temporary zip file. I thought this question and the answer to it will have some value if posted on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Inflate](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.InflatingOutputStream.html)/[Deflate](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.DeflatingOutputStream.html) streams provided in POCO:

> This stream compresses all data passing through it using zlib's
>   deflate algorithm. After all data has been written to the stream,
>   close() must be called to ensure completion of compression.

```
std::ofstream ostr("data.gz", std::ios::binary);
DeflatingOutputStream deflater(ostr, DeflatingStreamBuf::STREAM_GZIP);
deflater << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
deflater.close();
ostr.close();
```

You can redirect that `ostr` to your TCP stream.

Comment: But it creates the zip in memory, does it not? And if it doesn't how can I control the size of the in memory buffer?

Comment: It creates zip partially in memory (buffers) and writes that buffered part in the stream. You can manage the buffer by controlling `streambuf` of output stream. And also you can replace that `ofstream` by another output stream that you can control it.

Comment: Note that this is a GZ file, which is similar to ZIP but not the same--you can't send multiple files inside a GZ, for instance.